# Is it possible to find all collections in Firestore without knowing their paths apriori?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I believe that Firestore queries for documents that only contain subcollections and not any fields are not supported. Is there any way to find all subcollections? It seems theoretically possible as the Firestore console supports viewing subcollections.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [ListCollectionIds](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1beta1#google.firestore.v1beta1.Firestore.ListCollectionIds) to list all of the collection ids.  The rest api request url would look something like: /v1beta1/projects/{project-id}/databases/(default)/documents/topics:listCollectionIds?pageSize=3